# Making changes to AVCaptureSession disrupts background audio

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I am using an `AVCaptureSession` to record video, and I also support audio from other apps while doing this. Whenever I make changes to the `AVCaptureSession`, such as toggling the camera between front/back, the audio coming from Music or Spotify lags for about a second. This does not happen when toggling camera in Snapchat, so there must be a way around it. They do have a small lag when initiating the camera, but not when toggling it.

[This post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/74778#74778) mentions that switching between audio-only routes to video recording routes is such a big change that a small lag is expected, but I don't touch the `AVAudioSessionCategory` while switching the cameras.

This is how I change between the camera inputs:

```
- (void)changeCamera
{
    dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue, ^{
        AVCaptureDevice *currentVideoDevice = [self.videoDeviceInput device];
        AVCaptureDevicePosition preferredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionUnspecified;
        AVCaptureDevicePosition currentPosition = [currentVideoDevice position];

        switch (currentPosition)
        {
            case AVCaptureDevicePositionUnspecified:
                preferredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
                self.position = EACameraPositionBack;
                break;
            case AVCaptureDevicePositionBack:
                preferredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;
                self.position = EACameraPositionFront;
                break;
            case AVCaptureDevicePositionFront:
                preferredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
                self.position = EACameraPositionBack;
                break;
        }

        AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [self deviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferringPosition:preferredPosition];

        AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:nil];

        [[self session] beginConfiguration];

        [[self session] removeInput:[self videoDeviceInput]];
        if ([[self session] canAddInput:videoDeviceInput])
        {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification object:currentVideoDevice];

            [self.cameraFlash setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeAuto torchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeAuto forDevice:videoDevice];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(subjectAreaDidChange:) name:AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification object:videoDevice];

            [[self session] addInput:videoDeviceInput];
            [self setVideoDeviceInput:videoDeviceInput];
        }
        else
        {
            [[self session] addInput:[self videoDeviceInput]];
        }

        [[self session] commitConfiguration];
    });
}
```